# AutoFixture AutoMoq problem getting CallBase to work with injected Mock dependencies

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, autofixture, automoq

I'm using AutoFixture to create a service which has a repository dependency injected through the constructor. When using fixture.Create<>, a mock repository is automatically provided for the dependency. I'd like to use CallBase on the mock repository so that it calls the method on the actual underlying class. Is this possible? The methods are defined as virtual so that Moq can override them. Below is a basic example and a test with AutoFixture which fails. Then the same test is shown using Moq directly which succeeds. The testing library being used is xUnit. Assume the interfaces have the shown methods defined.

Service:

```
    public class PersonService : IPersonService {
        private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;

        public PersonService(IPersonRepository personRepository) {
            _personRepository = personRepository;
        }

        public virtual string GetPersonName(int id) => _personRepository.GetPersonName(id);
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository {
        public virtual string GetPersonName(int id) => Data.People[id].FirstName!;
    }
```

Data:

```
    public static class Data {
        public static List<Person> People { get; } = new() {
            new Person { FirstName = "Jack" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Jill" }
        };
    }
```

Person:

```
    public class Person {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Failing Test with AutoFixture: result is null, the GetPersonName method on the repo is never called via CallBase

```
        [Fact]
        public void AutoFixture_Test_CallBase() {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

            var mockPersonRepository = fixture.Freeze<Mock<PersonRepository>>();
            mockPersonRepository.Setup(r => r.GetPersonName(It.IsAny<int>())).CallBase();

            var sut = fixture.Create<PersonService>();
            var result = sut.GetPersonName(1);

            Assert.Equal(Data.People[1].FirstName, result);
        }
```

The same test works fine using Moq without AutoFixture:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Moq_Test_CallBase() {
            var mockPersonRepository = new Mock<PersonRepository>();
            mockPersonRepository.Setup(r => r.GetPersonName(It.IsAny<int>())).CallBase();

            var sut = new PersonService(mockPersonRepository.Object);
            var result = sut.GetPersonName(1);

            Assert.Equal(Data.People[1].FirstName, result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when `PersonService` is created by AutoFixture, it uses the `Mock<IPersonRepository>` to build up an `IPersonRepository` but in your code it is not defined so it uses the default.

Since you want to setup the `Mock<IPersonRepository>` with `CallBase`, one approach would be to freeze a `Mock<PersonRepository>` and then, whenever an `IPersonRepository` is required by AutoFixture to build up any other object that depends on it (like the `PersonService`) you call `fixture.Create<PersonRepository>()`

So it'd be like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void AutoFixture_Test_CallBase()
{
   var fixture = new Fixture();
   fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

   var mockPersonRepository = fixture.Freeze<Mock<PersonRepository>>();
   mockPersonRepository
      .Setup(r => r.GetPersonName(It.IsAny<int>()))
      .CallBase();

   fixture.Register<IPersonRepository>(() => fixture.Create<PersonRepository>());

   var sut = fixture.Create<PersonService>();
   var result = sut.GetPersonName(1);

   Assert.Equal(Data.People[1].FirstName, result);
}
```

Comment: Well that definitely works! Thanks so much for the solution. I've been searching all over for how to do this, and I haven't come across a single mention of fixture.Register<>, but that seems like it does exactly what I wanted. This was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: It looks like you don't even need to create, freeze, or setup the Mock<PersonRepository>.  I guess Fixture.Register is just telling AutoFixture to use what's created by the creation function whenever the interface is asked for, without mocking or CallBase even being involved. The Mock with CallBase can be made to work by doing var mockPersonRepository = new Mock<PersonRepository>(); and calling Register with a creation function of () => mockPersonRepository.Object. I guess Fixture.Freeze just doesn't create the Mock the same way that new Mock<T> does.

Comment: I understand better now. AutoFixture.AutoMoq only creates a Mock if it falls through the AutoFixture engine, which happens if it's an interface or an abstract class. If it's a concrete class, then AutoFixture creates the instance, and it's not mocked.